# heatmaply Can't Reorder without Displaying Dendrogram

Tags: r, heatmap, heatmaply

I wish to reorder the rows but not show the dendrogram with heatmaply, this code runs but doesn't do this:

```
colorStand <- colorRampPalette(colors = c("blue", "white", "red"))
heatmaply(data, margins = c(60,100,40,20),colors=colorStand,limits = c(-2.5,2.5),showticklabels = c(T,F),Rowv=TRUE, Colv=TRUE,dendrogram='column')
```

I think the Rowv=TRUE should have worked

Comment: Hi there, this feature does not yet exist with heatmaply. You can open an issue about it here: https://github.com/talgalili/heatmaply/issues and we'll give this a look